# How to finish an activity before is being displayed?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have in my app two activities. This is how I added them in the Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".auth.SignInActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".main.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In both activities I have a listener that helps me check the state of the user. If the user is logged-in I send the user to the `MainActivity` otherwise to the `SignInActivity`.

The problem is when the user is **not** logged-in. When opening the app, the user is redirected to the `MainActivity`. Since to check if the user is logged-in takes some time, the users sees the `MainActivity` for a few seconds till is redirected to the `SignInActivity`.

So when the user is not logged in, how can I stop the `MainActivity` from being displayed even for those few seconds?

Comment: Add a Splash Activity first which should decide where to go.

Comment: Fragments may be useful

Comment: Generally, we use SplashScreen for that.

Comment: @SharpEdge Thanks for your comment but you say that instead of seeing the MainActivity to show a SplashActivity, but is there any solution not to display any activity at all?

Comment: @JAB Can you provide me an example?

Comment: @GreenROBO Is there any other alternative?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

You will switch to one fragment or the other whether the user is logged in or not. All within a single activity.

Comment: Your design is flawed. If you want to determine where user lands as soon as the app opens that's where a Splash Activity comes in handy. Show a generic Splash Screen and it's onCreate decide if the user if login or not, then route the user accordingly.

Comment: The answers are correct. For your specific case (if you don't want to use a SplashActivity) then change the order of launching activities. Go with SignIn (where you check the state of user) and launch next one accordingly

Note, if you do as I said, you'll have to add the <intent-filter> to SignInActivity and remove it from Main :)

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan Thanks for your comment but if I change the order and I'm logged in this time, the `SignInActivity` is displayed for a few seconds. Are  you sure about that?

Comment: Depends on how you make the check of user state. If you check it in onCreate of SignInActivity, and it takes a lot of time (a request is made or a long time database transaction) then show a UI progress then just start the MainActivity.

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan So you say that is better to display a `ProgressBar` for the UI progress instead of using a splash activity?

Comment: I don't say it is better. I said, that in the case when you don't want an extra activity (Splash one)

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan Thank you for this hint. I'll consider using in a future project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can create a SplashActivity where you can check user's state

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //show a splash image and check user's state then redirect to correct screen
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you say that instead of seeing the `MainActivity` to show a `SplashActivity`, but is there any solution not to display any activity at all?

Comment: It would create bad user experience though because user will see white or black screen for a period of time and they will think the app is lagging when opening it

Comment: So you say that it's better to display a custom activity rather than a blank or any other activity, right?

Comment: Glad that I help

Answer (score 3):

Either you can include a splashscreen to get your job done.
Or else you can call your setcontentview() or corresponding ui elements after your checking method gets done.

Comment: What do you mean with "call your setcontentview() "?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); which we call generally in onCreate(). But, probably it should be showing an empty white screen as already mentioned by @Bach Vu

Comment: Have you made another splash activity or did something different?

Comment: Yes, it did it with a splash activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Using a Launcher Theme with a Dedicated Splash Activity**
 method as mentioned as method 2 at
https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565

this is the right way to do it